# Sharing Server Side data to a JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I've created a simple blog site, with posts, users and comments.
I'm using - MongoDB, NodeJS and Express with an EJS view.
I've encounterd a problem when I tried to create the comments sections.
I wanted to use JQuery with Ajax requests in order to make the comments section 
so the page won't refresh when a user is posting a comment or edting one.

In order to get the comments for each post, I built an api route that look like this - www.domain.com/api/messages/:post_id
this url returns JSON that contains the comments for that post.
I didn't want to expose 'risky' data about the author of the comment so I fillterd the results with the Mongo query.

**Now for the problem -** 
I want to add edit and delete buttons for each comment, that would show up only for the admin and the author of course.
When I use EJS its simple - I wrote something like this -

```
<% if (user !== null&& (JSON.stringify(user._id) === JSON.stringify(comments[i].author._id) 
|| user.is_admin === true)) { %> 
put the buttons here...
```

The thing is, when I'm using JQuery on my main scirpt file, I can't access the user (that's an object that was sent from Nodejs on the backend).
I'm not sure if I should 'send' this object to my js file from the EJS, I think it's not secure and not the right way.

And I can't also keep that EJS code I quoted a few lines ago because when the EJS file loads there are no comments on that page (the XHR request gets them and JQuery puts them on the page).
So I'm really not sure how to move on.

Edit - I think i have a solution: Maybe I should create an array of IDs on the EJS file that would contain the comments that need to have these buttons, and then I would send that array to the JS file somehow?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes you're right about its not secure way to send user Object to client side code from `ejs` as someone can just do `user.is_admin = true` to get those buttons. So what you can do is have a hidden div containing `ejs` code and show the div when your comments are finished loading.

Comment: Thanks! I dont think I understood your solution, the commenta are fetched with an xhr request, so what should I hide in the ejs file? When its loading there are no comments on the page

Comment: I meant you can hide your buttons till the comments aren't loaded in the ejs way.

Answer (score 0):

Send the user and all comments to the main `EJS` file.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        comments: [{ ... }, { ... }, { ... }], 
        user: { ... }
    });
});
```

The comments can be rendered by including [a EJS partial](https://github.com/tj/ejs#includes) `comment.ejs` from the folder `partials` in the main `EJS`  file.

```
<% comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
    <% include partials/comment %>
<% }) %>
```

In that `partial` you render the comment and buttons. The comment is past through to the include. The user already lives on the main `EJS` template.

```
<div class="comment-container" data-commentid="comment._id">
    <p><% comment.content %></p>
    <% if (user !== null&& (JSON.stringify(user._id) === JSON.stringify(comment.author._id) || user.is_admin === true)) { %> 
        <button class="button_delete" data-commentid="<% comments_id %>">delete</button>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Then create a `route` in your `API` like www.domain.com/api/messages/delete/:post_id.

```
app.get('/messages/delete/:post_id', function(req, res){
    // logged on user lives on the server
    // check if user may delete comments
    // delete comment
    // send result
    res.send(true);
});
```

When you click the `button` use `jQuery` to send that id from the `data attribute` of the `button` to the `server/api` and from there I would Identify the user that's logged on. If the logged on user is authorized delete it and send back the result. If everything is okay use `jQuery` to delete the div containing the whole message.

```
$('.button_delete').click(function(){
    // retrieve id from data attribute here
    var commentId = $(this).data("commentid");

    $.get('www.domain.com/api/messages/delete/' + commentId, {}, function(result){
        if(result) {
            // delete comment container from html using commentId or refresh
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!
but I think you didn't understand my question, I need to know when to display the delete button itslef. If you could read my edit I think that would make things clearer.

Comment: I clarified my answer. There is no need to use jQuery to load your comments. Use partials to render each comment.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a very different solution from what I had in mind, because i though once you're going the XHR route, it's better to use it for both getting and posting (deleting). Thanks for the very comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I managed to overcome this problem, I'll post what I did so hopefully it will help someone in the future.

In the **EJS** file, I assigned an array that will hold the ID's of the comments that were published by the current user (The user was sent to the EJS file by the nodejd backend).

Then, I copied this array to a script tag variable in the EJS file, By doing that, I can now access it from the main.js file, and add the delete/edit buttons only to comments that have an ID that's in the array.

```
<% var arr = []; %>
<% for(var i = 0; i < comments.length ; i++){ %>
 <% if (user !== null && (JSON.stringify(user._id) === JSON.stringify(comments[i].author._id) || user.is_admin === true)) { %>
 <% arr.push(comments[i].comment_id); %> <% } %>
 <% } %>
 <script> 
var exported_array = <%- JSON.stringify(arr) %>
 </script>
```